# How to merge redundant json properties in JSON.net

Tags: c#, json.net

I have two JObjects:

```
JObject firstObject = new JObject()
{
    { "redundantKey", "value1" }
}

JObject secondObject = new JObject()
{
    { "redundantKey", "value2" }
}
```

Is there a way to merge the secondObject into the firstObject, but keep "value1" in the merged jobject?

In essence: How do I decide which JObject's redundant properties get kept during a merge?

This works, but I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way that avoids reassignment:

```
secondObject.Merge(firstObject);
firstObject = secondObject;
```

Comment: Is [`JContainer.Merge()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/MergeJson.htm) not working for you?  If you do `secondObject.Merge(firstObject)` then the values from the 1st will supersede the values from the second.

Comment: @dbc but how do I firstObject.Merge(secondObject) and keep the firstObjects values without reassigning firstObject?

Comment: Merge it back again?   Can you share what you've done so far and why it's not working?  I have this feeling there might be a bit of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here, though I can't be sure.